# JSON Call JS Display Date formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Using JSON, I was able to successfully loop through a directory and display the files with path and date. However, I'm not sure how to change the output. I'd like to just display Month and Year instead of Day Month Day Year.

```
$.getJSON( "http://www.houston.org/api/v1/forms/dir", function( data ) {
            data.forEach(function(o,i){
                $('#arChives').append('<div><a href="'+o.Path+'/'+ o.Name+'">'+ new Date(o.Created).toDateString()+'</a></div>');
                });
        });

<div id="arChives"></div>
```

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nf5x/72/) sample

In addition to this question (not sure if I was supposed to ask this question separately), I'd like to capture the files creation date OR date last modified. As is, as I add new docs to the /dir/ folder, the date associated with each file is ultimately rendering the same... even though the last modified date is clearly from January. How do I accurately capture and render the files created date or last modified date?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to format the date  :

```
moment(Date(o.Created)).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nf5x/74/)

Comment: Thanks so much, Yoann! I was really looking for example:
January 2014
February 2014
March 2014
etc..etc.
But I guess I can go with this format. Thanks again!

Comment: If you do know how to format for example: January 2014
e.g. [month] [year]
Please fiddle - thanks!

Comment: Duh...nevermind - I figured it out ... I was making it harder than it was ... my bad. Thanks again!